MAUI landscape mode grid issues
I'm trying to get a grid to keep an aspect ratio of 2:1 in terms of height and width. I'm forcing landscape mode and have the following grid setup:
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:game="clr-namespace:MyApp_Mobile"
         x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
         x:Name="contentMain"
         x:DataType="thisapp:MainPageViewModel" IconImageSource="app_icon.png"
         LayoutChanged="ContentPage_LayoutChanged" Appearing="contentMain_Appearing" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="gridLayoutBox" BackgroundColor="{Binding boxColour}"  IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">

    </Grid>


Sadly it doesn't work as expected and doesn't seem to start in column 0. It also doesn't adhere to the column and row dimensions:

I want that blue rectangle to be twice the width of it's height - and begin in the upper left corner. I've tried switching to 6 rows and 3 columns, but I get a similar issue:

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly as I never had this issue in Xamarin?
Thanks,
Mike
EDIT
so making the change suggested initially fixed it, but once I started adding in controls to the last column I get the following display:
 <Grid>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="gridLayoutBox" 
          BackgroundColor="{Binding boxColour}"  
          IsClippedToBounds="True" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="6" 
          Grid.RowSpan="3" >

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listviewPlayers" HorizontalOptions="End" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" HeightRequest="700" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" RowHeight="15" SeparatorColor="Black" Grid.Column="6" Grid.RowSpan="3" >
        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="Games" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="Score" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="Name" TextColor="Black"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="game:Player">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid HeightRequest="25">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black">

                        </Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CurrentScore}" FontSize="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">

                        </Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding GamesWon}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black">
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


Then removing the controls in hot reload doesn't revert to the original, correctly placed gridbox??
I ported this directly from Xamarin, and it all worked fine.
It seems to be the listview that breaks things.

Can you show the code about the LayoutChanged and Appearing? I can't reproduce your problem.

Your layout code does not look anything like the screenshots you have. Why do you have reference "gridLayoutBox"? What are you doing to it?

There's nothing in LayoutChanged
private void contentMain_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
contentMain.BindingContext = viewModel;
viewModel.TableColour = Statics.Colour;
}

I copied your code and just add Grid.RowSpan="3" for the grid. And then I get the effect you want without LayoutChanged and Appearing.
The full xaml:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp7.MainPage" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Pink">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="gridLayoutBox" 
              BackgroundColor="Blue"  
              IsClippedToBounds="True" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="6" 
              Grid.RowSpan="3" >

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

And the result image:

In addition, if you want to force landscape, you can all the following code in the Page's OnHandlerChanged method or OnAppearing method.
#if ANDROID
Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
#endif

And in the Portrait mode, the blue grid will be cut off beacause its width is bigger than the screen's width.

I've edited the question with a bit more - it seems adding controls back in cause the problem again.

So when I initially load the app - the UI is in a weird state - as shown in the question. But if I remove and re-add the grid detailed above by Liyun Zhang, then it fixes the layout in the hot reload view. Not really sure why this is occurring, but it's a workable workaround.
